# Photoshop - Trim image so it fills canvas then resize to a set dimension?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, crop

I have been photographing and editing shoes on a regular basis for a local company. The images have been clipped so all the backgrounds are the same colours. I've been trying to speed up my workflow as I shoot about about 500 images a week.

I discovered the trim tool in photoshop cc which is awesome for cropping really close to the image, but then I have to re-crop manually to get the canvas square - 2000px by 2000px. Is there a quicker way of cropping an image to the edge of the shoe then adding more canvas so it's all 2000px?

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Lewis

Answer (score 1):

### Use [Actions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html)

Set up an action that does the steps you need to repeat. From the Actions panel hit the 'New Action' button and name it. Hit 'Record'. Then do the steps you want to record (e.g Resize, Trim, Canvas size: 2000 x 2000px).

You can then use your action, either when you are editing each image by hitting play with the action selected in the Actions panel or by assigning it to a key combination. Or you can go to **File → Automate → Batch...** and use your action on a whole folder of images (or all your open documents).

Comment: Thank you Cai. My issue seems to be that when it trims, it doesn't trim square. So that's why I manually crop to extend the canvas to a square format. So I need to trim then add more canvas automatically but I can't seem to figure that out. Maybe i'm asking the wrong question?

Comment: As I said, set up an action that does the trim then sets the canvas size. Whats the issue with doing that?

Comment: @Cal is spot on. You don't want to 'Crop', you want to set the canvas size.`Image > Canvas Size (ctrl+alt+c)` is the shortcut to setting the canvas size. Select 2000 x 2000px. job done. You can set this up as an action as he said